# WordPress multisite ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS where the domain name ends up in the path for nonexistent pages

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, too-many-redirects

I have a WordPress multisite setup with subdomains. I have pointed five subdomains to it. I have also installed SSL to main domain and the other subdomains.

I have written the below Redirect code for redirecting the non-www main domain to www, and all (main domain+sub-domains) to https.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Till then it is fine.

But, when I am going to any 404 urls like `https://www.example.com/any-404-page`, it is redirecting me to `https://www.example.com/www.example.com` and it is returning **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Is it happening because of my .htaccess code?

Comment: Did you write those rules yourself?  Why do you us `http%1` rather than `https` in the last line?  It looks like you are trying to capture the `s` from the second line, but I don't see how that is going to work because there are also capturing groups on the first line.   If you always what `https` why wouldn't you just specify that rather than trying to use capturing groups?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "but I don't see how that is going to work because there are also capturing groups on the first line" - that regex is a bit confusing. However, the `%1` refers to the _last matched_ CondPattern only and the condition `%{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|` is always successful. The trailing `|` (alternation) is key and effectively matches _anything_ - although nothing is actually "matched" - the expression is successful. For `http`, the `%1` backreference is simply not defined and results in an empty string. However, as you suggest, there are other issues with those directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of `NOBLOGREDIRECT` constant in WordPress.
I had defined the `NOBLOGREDIRECT` as `www.example.com`, so if that URL does not exist, then it redirects to `https://www.example.com/www.example.com`.

I have changed `NOBLOGREDIRECT` from `www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com` and now it is redirecting to home page.

Comment: I wouldn't use a rule to redirect non-existent pages to the home page.  It isn't good for users.   Users benefit from specific redirects to deep pages when there is an change in URL or an obvious mis-typing of the URL.     Search engine bots expect to find 404 errors.   They view it as a sign of a healthy site that non-existent pages return the correct error code (404).   Google treats redirects to the home page as "soft 404" errors and those redirects will appear in your Google Search Console error reports.

Comment: That is a bug or feature of Wordpress multisite. There are some other action hooks & filter which we can use to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have written the below Redirect code for redirecting the non-www main domain to www, and all (main domain+sub-domains) to https.
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
> RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

This is possibly an aside to your immediate problem, however, this code does not do what you say it does. In fact, as it stands, this code does nothing at all for subdomains, as you appear to suggest!?

Specifically...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
> ```

This *condition* will never be successful for any subdomains or a *fully qualified* main domain (all valid hostnames, apart from the main domain in the case of single-level TLDs, will have at least 2 dot segments), so the following `RewriteRule` will never get processed.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
> RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

This will always redirect HTTP to HTTP and HTTPS to HTTPS, it does not redirect HTTP to HTTPS. If you need that then you should hardcode the `s` the the *substitution*, as @Stephen suggested in comments.